# How to load specific column from a .csv file into a 2D array? Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a .csv file looks like this:

```
ID Name Zip  Lat     Lng
1  Joe  1001 23.234  54.234
2  Mike 1002 24.234  54.231
3  Amy  1003 26.234  54.232
```

From the file I only need Name, Lat and Lng, how can I only store this 3 column in to a 2-D array? something like this:

```
     [
      [Joe, 23.234, 54.234],
      [Mike, 24.234, 54.231],
      [Amy, 26.234, 54.232]
                            ]
```

```
def loadVsCSV(path):
    data = []
    with open(path) as file:
        rows = csv.reader(file)
    return(data)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library for your task

```
#import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

#load the csv file, specify your filename
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

#drop the column that is not required
df1 = df.drop(['ID', 'Zip'], axis = 1)

#convert dataframe to numpy array
df1_array = df1.to_numpy()
print(df1_array)


Result:
[['Joe' 23.243000000000002 54.243]
 ['Mike' 24.243000000000002 54.231]
 ['Amy' 26.243000000000002 54.232]]
```

Comment: thx for the answer, how can the results be like this [Joe, 23.234, 54.234]? has a ", " between each value?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use an external lib - see below. Read the file lines, for each line - split it into fields and collect the 'interesting' fields.

```
out = []
with open('1.csv') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()][1:]
    for line in lines:
        temp = line.split()
        out.append([temp[1],
                    float(temp[3]),
                    float(temp[4])])
print(out)
```

output

```
[['Joe', 23.234, 54.234], ['Mike', 24.234, 54.231], ['Amy', 26.234, 54.232]]
```